# Best way to submit a form and keep working

Tags: php, forms

I have a PHP page, with a form, the form submit variable to a PHP script that start working calling several Programs

IF i submit this form in the same tab, if a change the url by clicking some element in the navbar the form stop working.

If i submit the form to another tab i can't click anything in the original tab unless the pipeline finish the work.

How i can handle this in the best way?

Comment: Create a switch in your database, *1/0* for a cronjob to work on a timely fashion

Answer (score 2):

If you are not interested in the "outcome" of the script (let's say its just important, that it finishes)

you can add `ignore_user_abort(true)` to the script processing the form: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

Then, PHP will finish the script no matter if the user switches the page.

If you NEED the result of the script, you would need to implement some asynchronous javascript to keep track of the current processing state - or have the user wait until its done.

Depending on how long this script will run, you maybe also need to increase the time limit:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

But keep in mind, that most of the users will wait until they receive some visual feedback of the submission. So if it takes 10 Minutes, it might be a bad idea to process the request in an synchronous way, if you don't really need it like that.

Comment: I also try a ajax async call, but if i change the page, the script i call finish

Comment: @Christian: Call it async, and add the value `ignore_user_abort` to the processing file. User will get immediate feedback (*Your request has been scheduled for execution*), script will run until its done.

Comment: i put async:true in the ajax call, and ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0); If i try to change the page it doesn't work until the script finish totally